# cant fit a curve (x**3.4 + x**0.7) using universal approximate theorem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to learn a model(single hidden layer) which can fit the curve x**(3.4)+x**(0.7)

But it's not fitting even if i use 1000 width hidden layer

Here is the notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vap3SExRmsA3GBK6Kg2eoSlhgt-5v7qP

can anyone explain whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your model inputs in the range 0-2, while the network can only generate 0-1 outputs. Try normalizing your inputs first. One simple way is to divide by the max of all training inputs. I'm sure torch offers other ways to normalize the input as well.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LAosaHTE76ekZ3FSyJwjOyHPXDVL35vk